# Delete From in delete after trigger not deleting from another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a DELETE TRIGGER so that when a row is deleted from a table `Bike` it will delete a row in another table called `Available` as long as it is not in a different table called in `Rental`. If it is in `Rental` table then it will cancel the delete (if that's possible I'm very new to sql).

```
BEGIN
DELETE FROM Available 
Where old.bnumber = Available.bnumber;
END
```

right now I am getting

> 1451: Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint
> fails (`cecs535project`.`available`, CONSTRAINT `bnumber` FOREIGN KEY
> (`bnumber`) REFERENCES `bike` (`bnumber`))

bnumber is a foreign key in Available that references `Bike`.

Any help is appreciated.

```
CREATE TABLE `Bike` (
  `bnumber` int NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bnumber`)
)

CREATE TABLE `Available` (
  `bnumber` int NOT NULL,
  `rack-id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bnumber`),
  KEY `bnumber_idx` (`rack-id`),
  KEY `bnumber_idx1` (`bnumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `bnumber` FOREIGN KEY (`bnumber`) REFERENCES `Bike` (`bnumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `rack-id` FOREIGN KEY (`rack-id`) REFERENCES `Rack` (`id`)
) 

CREATE TABLE `Rental` (
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `time` time NOT NULL,
  `bnumber` int NOT NULL,
  `cust-id` int NOT NULL,
  `src` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bnumber`,`cust-id`,`date`,`time`),
  KEY `bnumber_idx` (`bnumber`),
  KEY `cust-id_idx` (`cust-id`),
  KEY `src_idx` (`src`),
  CONSTRAINT `bike` FOREIGN KEY (`bnumber`) REFERENCES `Bike` (`bnumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `cust-id` FOREIGN KEY (`cust-id`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `src` FOREIGN KEY (`src`) REFERENCES `Rack` (`id`)
)
```

Comment: Provide complete scheme as CREATE TABLE scripts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possible approaches

1. Use signal to identify where rental exists an throw an error https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/signal.html
2. test for rental existence in delete;

In both a before trigger is used since the constraint test occurs before an after trigger fires.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS AVAILABLE;
drop table if exists rental;
drop table if exists BIKE;

CREATE TABLE `Bike` (
  `bnumber` int NOT NULL,
  `make` varchar(64) DEFAULT NULL,
  `color` varchar(8) DEFAULT NULL,
  `year` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bnumber`)
);

insert into bike values
(10,'aaa','red',2020),(20,'bbb','yell',2020);

CREATE TABLE `Available` (
  `bnumber` int NOT NULL,
  `rack-id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`bnumber`),
  KEY `bnumber_idx` (`rack-id`),
  KEY `bnumber_idx1` (`bnumber`),
  CONSTRAINT `bnumber` FOREIGN KEY (`bnumber`) REFERENCES `Bike` (`bnumber`)#,
  #CONSTRAINT `rack-id` FOREIGN KEY (`rack-id`) REFERENCES `Rack` (`id`)
) ;

insert into available values
(10,100),(20,200);

CREATE TABLE `Rental` (
  #`date` date NOT NULL,
  #`time` time NOT NULL,
  `bnumber` int NOT NULL,
  #`cust-id` int NOT NULL,
  #`src` int DEFAULT NULL,
  #PRIMARY KEY (`bnumber`,`cust-id`,`date`,`time`),
  KEY `bnumber_idx` (`bnumber`),
  #KEY `cust-id_idx` (`cust-id`),
  #KEY `src_idx` (`src`),
  CONSTRAINT `bike` FOREIGN KEY (`bnumber`) REFERENCES `Bike` (`bnumber`)#,
  #CONSTRAINT `cust-id` FOREIGN KEY (`cust-id`) REFERENCES `Customer` (`id`),
  #CONSTRAINT `src` FOREIGN KEY (`src`) REFERENCES `Rack` (`id`)
) ;

insert into rental values
(10);
```

Approach 1

```
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t before delete on bike
for each row 
begin
    if exists (select 1 from rental r where r.bnumber = old.bnumber) then
           SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'An error occurred Rental exists';
    end if;
    delete a from available a where a.bnumber = old.bnumber;

end $$
delimiter ;

delete b  from bike b;
ERROR 1644 (45000): An error occurred Rental exists

+---------+------+-------+------+
| bnumber | make | color | year |
+---------+------+-------+------+
|      10 | aaa  | red   | 2020 |
|      20 | bbb  | yell  | 2020 |
+---------+------+-------+------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)

select * from available;
+---------+---------+
| bnumber | rack-id |
+---------+---------+
|      10 |     100 |
|      20 |     200 |
+---------+---------+
2 rows in set (0.001 sec)
select * from rental;
+---------+
| bnumber |
+---------+
|      10 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Approach 2

```
drop trigger if exists t;
delimiter $$
create trigger t before delete on bike
for each row 
begin
    delete a from available a where a.bnumber = old.bnumber;

end $$
delimiter ;

delete b  from bike b  where 
            #bnumber = 10 and 
            not exists(select 1 from rental r where r.bnumber = b.bnumber);
            
select * from bike; 

 +---------+------+-------+------+
| bnumber | make | color | year |
+---------+------+-------+------+
|      10 | aaa  | red   | 2020 |
+---------+------+-------+------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

select * from available;
+---------+---------+
| bnumber | rack-id |
+---------+---------+
|      10 |     100 |
+---------+---------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)

select * from rental;
+---------+
| bnumber |
+---------+
|      10 |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.001 sec)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly I used the first approach thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I am not a big fan of your current design, and I think it can be simplified.  Consider just having a single table for all bike assets, with one column maintaining whether or not it be currently rented out, e.g.

```
Bike
id | name  | type     | rented (bit)
1  | bike1 | road     | 1
2  | bike2 | mountain | 0
...
```

Now to record a bike being rented or not, you simply have to update the `rented` bit column above.  Should you want to delete from your inventory, refraining from doing so if the bike be on loan, you can use:

```
DELETE
FROM Bike
WHERE rented = 0;  -- AND your other conditions here
```

Comment: It's for a school assignment and the tables being like that are how it is required. Otherwise I would also do it different.

Answer (score 0):

Creating an **AFTER DELETE** instead could also help to skip the Foreign Key Constraint issue

```
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
    AFTER DELETE
    ON table_name FOR EACH ROW
trigger_body;
```

ref: https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-triggers/mysql-after-delete-trigger/

Comment: I have tried doing after delete and before delete and they both give the same problem.